# Testing for bare git repository with ls-remote

Tags: git

I'd like to check to see if a bare git repository exists.  The following doesn't work on my Mac.  The `ls-remote` command says my repository is not a repository, but the `clone` command lets me clone it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
repos>  git init --bare --shared=all tmp.git
Initialized empty shared Git repository in 
/Users/raysalemi/workspaces/install_mcs_project/repos/tmp.git/
repos>  git ls-remote tmp.git
fatal: 'tmp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
repos>  ls
tmp.git
repos>  git clone tmp.git
Cloning into 'tmp'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
repos>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears `git ls-remote` only works with an absolute path.

Comment: `git ls-remote tmp.git` treats `tmp.git` as the name of a remote. You can spell out a URL, including a full path name, or be in a repository and use the remotes defined in that repository's configuration.